# Changing matplotlibs cachedir, but not config dir

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm running hundreds of parallel jobs on a HPC.  Each job creates plots using Matplotlib's LaTeX rendererr.  My home directory has a quota of 10 GB, and this is getting filled up by `~/.cache/matplotlib/tex.cache`.  According to the [troubleshooting FAQ](http://matplotlib.org/faq/troubleshooting_faq.html#matplotlib-configuration-and-cache-directory-locations):

> Note that MPLCONFIGDIR sets the location of both the configuration directory and the cache directory.

Is there any way I can change the location of the cache directory, *without* also changing the location of the configuration directory?

Comment: My current workaround is to make a symlink, then create the destination before importing matplotlib, but this solution might be not ideal.